# Can I see the exact UI hierarchy that EarlGrey uses to locate elements?

Tags: earlgrey

I am writing a test that fails with following error:

> Error Domain=com.google.earlgrey.ElementInteractionErrorDomain Code=0 "No element found." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No element found.}

I can see in the generated screenshot that the element I am trying to match exists. I stepped through the code and saw that earlgrey uses element providers. When my test failed, I saw a ui hierarchy dump. I want to print the exact same ui hierarchy at specific breakpoints instead. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `GREYElementHierarchy` class to print the element hierarchy at any point in your `EarlGrey` test.

`UIWindow *hierarchy = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window]);`

`NSLog(@"Hierarchy: %@", hierarchy);`

Answer (score 1):

As in [EarlGrey FAQ](https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/blob/master/docs/faq.md) you can add a breakpoint anywhere in your tests and, when hit, run in Xcode's debug window:

```
expression -- print(GREYElementHierarchy.hierarchyStringForAllUIWindows())
```

This will output the complete hierarchy so it will be a little confusing to parse out.

Good luck